# How to get a smooth emboss circle shape on a mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is there a method I can get a smooth embossed circle shape on a more condensed mesh. On the left I have very little subdivisions which makes a nice smooth transition, but not enough subdivision for more detailing around the circle shape. On the right Mesh, double the subdivisions but not good smooth transition. So what technique is best.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is [tweaking the topology](https://imgur.com/a/DyxQpgU) out of the question?

Comment: Please do share a topology sample so I can see how to improve, thank you.

Comment: what result do you want? the lower left or lower right?

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jXJq0ABQ/) ... making sure the base topo doesn't fight the circular profile.

Comment: @RobinBetts. I'm currently on Blender 3.4.1, can you please make it that version? I try opening up your file, and Blender crashes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a dense topology that needs to stay dense for some reason, do a bevel:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can play with vertex and edge creases and use a subdivision as starting point:

[image]